# Try moving EZCONNECT to the first position in NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH in the sqlnet.ora file

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c, ora-12541

When I try to drop a procedure in Oracle 12C I get a message saying `statement procesing` all the time.

I restarted the Oracle server from linux Oracle OS.

I now get this exception

```
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Items Checked

TNS_ADMIN environment variable is defined as "C:\app\edidinen\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\"

"C:\app\edidinen\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora" was located

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH specifies EZCONNECT in the sqlnet.ora file

EZCONNECT is not the first naming method in NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH which may conflict with other naming methods specified

Steps to Take
Try moving EZCONNECT to the first position in NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH in the sqlnet.ora file
Verify that the correct port is specified
Verify that the listener is running and that it is properly configured
Try to ping  192.168.1.118 using the Ping button on the toolbar
Try to TNSPing (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.118)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCLDB))) using the TNS Ping button on the toolbar
```

Comment: How does your `C:\app\edidinen\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora` file look like? It is a simple text tile.

Comment: sqlnet.ora ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /home/orcuser/app/orcuser/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

Comment: I think now it is quite obvious what you have to do according to error messages.

Comment: I couldn't see it. What should I do?
I have chaged the ora file to
<<
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
names.default_domain = WORLD 
trace_level_client = OFF 
sqlnet.expire_time = 30
<<
is it enough?

Comment: Maybe first of all: where did you get the error? Did you try proposed actions, i.e. `ping` and `tnsping`? Is the listener running?